# FIWARE Orion and pep proxy solutions?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wilma

From Orion documentations it has been mentionned that the two available PEP proxy are Wilma and Steelskin.
I want to list all the available options so is there an other open source solutions for securing FIWARE Orion?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orion is just an http service, so everything that you can use to protect http services is fine.
The best solution depends on your deployment scheme.

Within FIWARE you have the two that you mentioned:

- [Wilma](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy), very simple, works with Keystone;
- [Steelskin](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-pep-steelskin), more advanced, works with Keystone or Openstack Keyrock.

Other options may include:

- [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html?_ga=1.40659105.2067721636.1463189139), is typically used as a performant proxy and has authentication modules as well;
- [Squid](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication), is a widespread proxy and also supports authentication;
- [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011102/apache-reverse-proxy-with-basic-authentication), has widespread proxy and authentication modules, although it will probably be the bottleneck of the system.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the alternatives that you mention are the ones that exist. In particular:

- [Wilma](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy), as GEri of PEP Proxy GE
- [Steelskin](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-pep-steelskin), as additional GEi of PEP Proxy GE

(In order to understand the difference between GE, GEi and GEri, please have a look to [this post](https://ask.fiware.org/question/1/what-is-a-fiware-ge-and-a-gei/)).