# How to combine apache web server and custom logic?

Tags: java, apache, authentication, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to develop an API gateway for my web application.
I am authenticating the users using `oauth2.0` and generating `jwt`.
After a user is authenticated and authorized , I want to proxy the request to the application.

I need to develop the authentication mechanism since there are custom logic that I need to execute. But the proxy is standard and nothing special.

Instead of developing the proxy mechanism myself, I thought of using out of the box product like `apache httpd`.
I am pretty familiar with it and used it in a couple of projects as a proxy server, but never before added any custom functionality.

I need to add an authentication phase before the proxy is executed.
How can I achieve this with a known web server instead of developing my own?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011102/apache-reverse-proxy-with-basic-authentication

Comment: I would try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011102/apache-reverse-proxy-with-basic-authentication

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the other answers provide a way of using apache built-in auth mechanism. I need a way to use my own (add some functionality of my own) authentication. Is it possible?